# Looping correlation tests on same variables across more than two dataframes

Tags: r, correlation

Consider these three dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = runif(10,1,10), b = runif(10,1,10), c = runif(10,1,10))

df2 <- data.frame(a = runif(10,1,10), b = runif(10,1,10), c = runif(10,1,10))

df3 <- data.frame(a = runif(10,1,10), b = runif(10,1,10), c = runif(10,1,10))
```

I want to do a `cor.test` between column `a` against column `a`, `b` against `b` and `c` against `c` in all dfs – I can do it between each pair using and modifying code below but I want loop between all three dataframes in one go:

```
for (i in 1:length(df1)){

    cor.test(df1[,i],df2[,i])

}
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Why the markdown - was it not clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do the combination of object names with `combn`, get the values with `mget` in a `list`, and apply `cor.test` on each `list` and extract the `p.value`

```
combn(paste0("df", 1:3), 2, FUN = function(x) {
      x1 <- mget(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
     Map(function(x,y) cor.test(x,y)$p.value, x1[[1]], x1[[2]])})
```

---

Or another option is `corr.test` from `psych`

```
library(psych)
t(sapply(names(df1), function(nm) {
     x1 <- corr.test(data.frame(df1[nm], df2[nm], df3[nm]))$p
      x1[lower.tri(x1)]})))
```

Comment: Thank you once again akrun. I'm trying to do a spearman cor.test. However, when I do  `Map(function(x,y) cor.test(x,y)$estimate, x1[[1]], x1[[2]], method = "spearman")}` I get `Error in (function (x, y)  : unused argument (method = dots[[3]][[1]])`

Comment: @Bonono I guess you need `cor.test(x,y, method = "spearman")`

Comment: My problem has now become more complicated - what if the `dfs`were in a nested list? So `dflist1 <- list(df1,df2,df3) ; dflist2 <- list(df1,df2,df3); nest_list <- list(dflist1, dflist2)`. Would I have to assign each one to the global environment first, before using `combn()` etc?

Comment: @Bonono Can you post that as a new question as it would require change of codes

Comment: have done akrun, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40831975/looping-correlation-tests-within-nested-lists-on-same-variables-across-more-than